# Android: Web Services, Offline Capability

Tags: android, mysql

I am posting this question because I couldn't find any satisfactory answers online.

I am developing an Android App in which the data is fetched from the external server(in my case it's localhost MySQL server now) and displayed on the screen.

However, the constraint with this is that the person should always be connected to the internet to get all the data which can be viewed on the phone.

Now, what I would like to achieve is, once the data has been retrieved from the external server it should be stored on the device so that even though the user opens up the app without being connected to the internet, the previously fetched data should be showed to him.

In other words, I would like to have the offline capability.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the same for my app. Have a look at the code and you will understand how to do it. I have used Retrofit for the same. I have checked if the nursejson which is in sharedpreference is null. if it is null then continue further to hit API if not then load data from that sharedpreference.

To refresh the list, just check if you have internet connectivity and then delete that sharedpreference and call getnurse method again.

```
//After Oncreate
pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("CachedResponse", 0);
editor = pref.edit();
editor.apply();
// Call getNurses method
getNurses();



//Method to get Nurses
public void getNurses() {

    nurseJson = pref.getString("nurseJson", null);

    if (nurseJson != null) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        gson = new Gson();
        nurse = gson.fromJson(nurseJson, Nurse.class);
        nurseList = nurse.getNurse();
        namesArrayList.clear();

        for (String nurses : nurseList) {
            namesArrayList.add(nurses);
        }

        namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } else {

        Call<Nurse> call = apiInterface.getNursesList();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Nurse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Nurse> call, Response<Nurse> response) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                onItemsLoadComplete();

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    nurse = response.body();

                    nurseJson = new Gson().toJson(nurse);
                    editor.putString("nurseJson", nurseJson);
                    editor.commit();

                    nurseList = nurse.getNurse();

                    namesArrayList.clear();

                    for (String nurses : nurseList) {
                        namesArrayList.add(nurses);
                    }

                    namesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else {

                    utility.createSnackbar(coordinatorLayout, "Error Occurred, Please Try Again Later!");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Nurse> call, Throwable t) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                onItemsLoadComplete();

                if (t.getLocalizedMessage() != null) {

                    if (t.getLocalizedMessage().contains("Unable to resolve host")) {

                        utility.createSnackbar(coordinatorLayout, "Please Check Internet Connection!");

                    } else {

                        utility.createSnackbar(coordinatorLayout, "Error Occurred, Please Try Again Later!");

                    }

                } else {

                    utility.createSnackbar(coordinatorLayout, "Error Occurred, Please Try Again Later!");

                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```